# Django admin order by most recent related model creation

Tags: django

I have some models for a messaging system on my django site.

```
class Enquiry(models.Model):
    etc...

class Message(models.Model):
    enquiry = models.ForeignKeyField(Enquiry)
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    etc...
```

Each message has a foreign key to an enquiry. In the admin site I would like to be able to order the enquiries by the most recent received message. In a regular view, I can do this:

```
Enquiry.objects.annotate(latest_message=Max('message__sent_at')).order_by('-latest_message')
```

Is there a way to achieve this in the admin framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method for your model admin, and use the same approach that already works in your views.

My first suggestion was to try setting ordering for your model admin, but you reported that it didn't work.

```
class EnquiryAdmin"
    ordering = ['-message__sent_at']
```

Comment: First one didn't seem to work but get_queryset will do it. Thanks